# Toggle <div> base on value selected on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Category", @Model.Select(item => new SelectListItem
   {
       Value = item.Id.ToString(),
       Text = item.Name.ToString(),
       Selected = "select" == item.Id.ToString()
   }), new { @class = "form-control", id = "dropDownListClient" })
```

I have this dropdown list, it's some c# but this is not important.

```
    @foreach (var a in @ViewBag.Ann)
    {
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2>@a.Title</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h3>@a.CategoryName</h3>
                <button class="btn btn-info">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Show Details", "ShowDetails", new { id = a.Id })
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
    }
```

I want to sort this list of announcements. When a category will be selected, only announcement with that category will be displayed.

I don't know javascript that good..Hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like this:

```
$('#dropDownListClient').on('change',function(){
    var category = $(this).val();
    $('.panel-primary').hide();
    $(document).find('#'+category).parents('.panel-primary:first').show();
});
```

Comment: not working. But this gives me an idea. If I have a <h3> tag with Id that correspond with the category, how can I hide the parent div?

Comment: You can do `$('h3').parents('div:first').hide();`
The code I wrote in answer should work. Can you make a snippet here?

Comment: I need to hide every parent of h3 element expect that h3 element with id == categorySelected

Comment: $('#dropDownListClient').on('change',function(){
                    var category = $("#dropDownListClient option:selected").text();
                   
                    $('.panel-primary').css({ "display": "none" });
                  $(document).find('#'+category).parents('.panel-primary:first').css("display","block");
                });


this is working. It hides all the element with .panel-primary but when I want to display the element with that specific id, it displays only the first.
Why not all?